# Checkout using cvs command line in an AIX box

Tags: cvs, aix

I am struggling to do a checkout via a commandline from an AIX box.

We have been typically doing the checkouts and having the builds via hudson on a Wintel box (and the CVS server was hosted on the AIX box).

I am struggling with the basics.

I set the CVSROOT on the commandline

export CVSROOT=:ext:cvs@localhost:/cvsrepos

and trying to do simple commands: cvs co -c

and receiving this strange error:

**

> host: name -l NOT FOUND

**
cvs [checkout aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)

Appreciate any assistance

Thanks
Manglu

Comment: It looks like the problem is with rsh that is used under the hood. This error message comes from the rsh login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe problem was that the default ext used rsh under the hood.

I switched it over to ssh by setting the variable (CVS_RSH=ssh)

which was defaulting to rsh earlier.

The set up for ssh keys were done and now things work well.

Manglu